# Can the type of this function be declared in standard Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, monads

The following program compiles under GHC 8.0.2 with no language extensions, and produces the expected two lines of output.

However, it does not compile if the (non-top-level) type declaration for the value write' is removed.

Also, I cannot find any (top-level) type declaration for the function write.

I find this rather odd. If this is acceptable standard Haskell, surely it should be possible to create a type declaration for the function write.

So my question is: is there such a type declaration?

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT, runMaybeT)
import Control.Monad.Writer (MonadTrans, Writer, lift, runWriter, tell, when)
import ListT (ListT, toList) -- Volkov's list-t package

logging = True

write x = when logging write' where
    write' :: MonadTrans m => m (Writer [String]) ()
    write' = lift $ tell [x]

f :: ListT (Writer [String]) String
f = do
    write "Hello from f"
    return "ABC"

g :: MaybeT (Writer [String]) Int
g = do
    write "Hello from g"
    return 123

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ runWriter $ toList f
    print $ runWriter $ runMaybeT g
```

Comment: "However, it does not compile if the (non-top-level) type declaration for the value write' is removed" -- I can't reproduce this with GHC 8.2.2 and the latest version of the [*list-t* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-1.0.0.1/docs/ListT.html). Are you using something different? What the compiler error you get is?

Comment: duplode --- you are correct, this version DOES compile without the declaration for write'. I had made a last-minute simplification to my code, replacing Writer [String] by Writer String. I shall edit my question back to the Writer [String] version, in which the problem occurs. I shall also answer your other questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Using GHCi (remember to put this into a separate file and load it on GHCi's command line lest you get confused by GHCi's altered typing rules):

```
> :t write
write :: (Applicative (m (Writer [String])), MonadTrans m) => 
         String -> m (Writer [String]) ()
```

Why? Well,

```
write' :: MonadTrans m => m (Writer [String]) ()
when :: Applicative f => Bool -> f () -> f ()
when logging :: Applicative f => f () -> f ()
```

so, `when logging write'` must unify `write'`'s `m (Writer [String])` with `when loggings`'s `f`, causing the combined constraint `(Applicative (m (Writer [String])), MonadTrans m)`. But wait, let's remove the type signatures and see what the most general type is:

```
-- equivalent but slightly easier to talk about
write = when logging . lift . tell . (:[])

(:[]) :: a -> [a]
tell :: MonadWriter w m -> w -> m ()
lift :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => m a -> t m a
tell . (:[]) :: MonadWriter [a] m => a -> m ()
lift . tell . (:[]) :: (MonadWriter [a] m, MonadTrans t) => a -> t m ()
when logging . lift . tell . (:[]) = write
  :: (Applicative (t m), MonadWriter [a] m, MonadTrans t) => a -> t m ()
-- GHCi agrees
```

Per se, there's nothing wrong with this type. However, standard Haskell does not allow this. In standard Haskell, a constraint must be of the form `C v` or `C (v t1 t2 ...)` where `v` is a type variable. In the compiling case, this holds: the `Applicative` constraint has the type variable `m` on the outside, and the `MonadTrans` is just `m`. This is true in the non-compiling version, too, but we also have the constraint `MonadWriter ([] a) m`. `[]` is no type variable, so the type here is rejected. This constraint arises in the compiling version, too, but the type signatures nail the variables down to produce `MonadWriter [String] (Writer [String])`, which is immediately satisfied and does not need to appear in the context of `write`.

The restriction is lifted by enabling `FlexibleContexts` (preferably via a `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` pragma, but also maybe by `-XFlexibleContexts`). It originally existed to prevent things such as the following:

```
class C a where c :: a -> a
-- no instance C Int

foo :: C Int => Int
foo = c (5 :: Int)
-- with NoFlexibleContexts: foo's definition is in error
-- with FlexibleContexts: foo is fine; all usages of foo are in error for
-- not providing C Int. This might obscure the source of the problem.

-- slightly more insiduous
data Odd a = Odd a
-- no Eq (Odd a)

oddly (Odd 0) (Odd 0) = False
oddly l r = l == r
-- oddly :: (Num a, Eq (Odd a), Eq a) => Odd a -> Odd a -> Bool
-- Now the weird type is inferred! With FlexibleContexts,
-- the weird constraint can propagate quite far, causing errors in distant
-- places. This is confusing. NoFlexibleContexts places oddly in the spotlight.
```

But it happens to get in the way a lot when you have `MultiParamTypeClasses` on.